# Ошибка runtime error 80004005 unexpected python error: <error getting traceback.print extraction() failed>

Tags: python, excel, pandas

[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]Недавно начал использовать средства python в Excel. В экселе вызываю функцию python для этого использую библиотеку ExcelPython. Результат выполнения функции является запись Pandas.DataFrame() в другом excel файле и построение графика в нем. С первого взгляда вроде все в порядке, хорошо работает, но когда закрываю файл, в котором вызывается функция python и заново открываю все перестает работать, выводит ошибку runtime error 80004005 unexpected python error: .
использую python3.5, MS Excel 2010.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно решить эту проблему или из за чего появляется такая ошибка? Конечно же я уже погуглил, подобные ошибки увидел, но нечего полезного не нашел для данного случая. 
Буду благодарен за любую помощь.
Вот код, который вызывается из excel

```
from xlpython import *
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
import random
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
import xlsxwriter

@xlfunc
def median_score(y_true, model_predict):
    a = abs((y_true - model_predict)/y_true)
    a_list=[]
    for i in a:
        a_list.append(i)
    median = np.median(a_list)    
    del a_list, a
    return median
@xlfunc
def median_trainCount_scatterN(start,step,limit_train, file_name, result_file_name):

    data = pd.read_excel(str(file_name)+'.xlsx')
    target = "Цена"
    medianList = []
    count = []
    dannie = []    
    glob_test_size=0.3

    (trainDataPrWith, 
    testDataPrWith, 
    trainDependentPrWith,testDependentPrWith) = train_test_split(data.drop(target, axis=1),data[target],test_size=glob_test_size,random_state=123335)

    (trainDataPrWithout, 
    testDataPrWithout, 
    trainDependentPrWithout, 
    testDependentPrWithout) = train_test_split(data.drop([target,'Цена на аренду'], axis=1),data[target],test_size=glob_test_size,random_state=123335)

    if str(limit_train)=="None":
        max_data_count = len(trainDataPrWith)
    else: max_data_count = int(limit_train)
    for i in range(int(start), max_data_count, int(step)):
        rand = random.randint(1, 123548)
        trainDataPartWith = trainDataPrWith.sample(n=i,random_state=rand)
        trainDependentPartWith = trainDependentPrWith.sample(n=i,random_state=rand)
        trainDataPartWithout = trainDataPrWithout.sample(n=i,random_state=rand)
        trainDependentPartWithout = trainDependentPrWithout.sample(n=i,random_state=rand)

        rForFegWith = RandomForestRegressor()
        rForFegWith.fit(trainDataPartWith, trainDependentPartWith)
        rForFegWithout = RandomForestRegressor()
        rForFegWithout.fit(trainDataPartWithout, trainDependentPartWithout)

        metricc = "median_score"
        medianWith = median_score(testDependentPrWith, rForFegWith.predict(testDataPrWith))
        medianList.append(round(medianWith, 3))        
        count.append(i)
        dannie.append('С арендой')

        medianWithout = median_score(testDependentPrWithout, rForFegWithout.predict(testDataPrWithout))
        medianList.append(round(medianWithout, 3))        
        count.append(i)
        dannie.append('Без аренды')

    TestCount=pd.DataFrame(index=range(len(count)))
    TestCount['Количество обучающей выборки'] = None
    TestCount['Данные'] = None        

    TestCount['Количество обучающей выборки'] = count
    TestCount['median_score'] = medianList 
    TestCount['Данные'] = dannie

    a=pd.DataFrame(index=range(len(TestCount[TestCount['Данные']=='С арендой'])))
    a['Количество обучающей выборки']=None
    a['median_score_C_арендой']=None
    a['median_score_Без_аренды']=None
    a['Количество обучающей выборки'] = list(TestCount[TestCount['Данные']=='С арендой']['Количество обучающей выборки'])
    a['median_score_C_арендой'] = list(TestCount[TestCount['Данные']=='С арендой']['median_score'])
    a['median_score_Без_аренды'] = list(TestCount[TestCount['Данные']!='С арендой']['median_score'])
    del TestCount
    # writer = pd.ExcelWriter(str(result_file_name)+'.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(str(result_file_name)+'.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    a.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
    workbook  = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

    chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'scatter'})
    max_row = len(a)

    for i in range(len(a.columns)):
        if i==0:
            trendcol="blue"
        else:trendcol="red"
        col = i + 1
        chart.add_series({
            'name':       ['Sheet1', 0, col],
            'categories': ['Sheet1', 1, 0, max_row, 0],
            'values':     ['Sheet1', 1, col, max_row, col],
            'marker':     {'type': 'diamond', 'size': 8},
            'trendline': {'type': 'power',  'display_equation': True,
            'line': {'color': trendcol, 'width': 2,}}
        })
    chart.set_x_axis({'name': 'Количество обучающей выборки'})
    chart.set_y_axis({'name': 'median_score'})
    worksheet.insert_chart('E2', chart,  {'x_scale': 1.5, 'y_scale': 2})    
    writer.save()
```

Данные

```
data=pd.DataFrame({"Высокий":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0],
              "Низкий":[1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
              "Средный":[0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0],
              "Цена":[3300000,1800000,1850000,1290000,1890000,1350000,3400000,9000000,2100000,
                      3300000,1800000,1850000,1290000,1890000,1350000,3400000,9000000,2100000,
                      1330000,1390000,1250000,2050000,950000,1250000,1650000,1700000,3500000,
                      1550000,1600000,2050000,1850000,2500000, 280000],
              "Количество комнат":[1,1,2,1,3,1,2,3,2,1,1,2,1,3,1,2,3,2,1,2,3,3,1,2,4,
                                   1,3,2,3,1,1,3,3],
              "Тип объекта":[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
             "Общая площадь":[48,38,44,35,57,31,53,108,52,48,38,44,35,57,31,53,108,52,30,45.6,76
                              ,66,22,41,61,34,69,42,79,40,38,72,72],
              "Год постройки":[2005,1990,1959,0,0,1966,0,0,0,2005,1990,1959,0,0,1966,0,0,0,1966,2014
                               ,1990,1973,1980,1973,1968,1996,1996,1963,1936,2008,2017,0,0],
              "г. Киров (центр)":[1824,1495,3000,3000,3000,3000,395,1204,3000,1824,1495,3000,3000
                                  ,3000,3000,395,1204,3000,11000,20000,9000,3000,11000,16000,15000
                                  ,4100,715,1458,3000,5000,5700,3000,4000],
              "Расстояние до ближайшей школы":[149,372,515,185,486,470,438,201,184,149,372,515,185,486
                                               ,470,438,201,184,1100,312,130,276,1000,524,238,717,171,316
                                               ,157,94,518,652,652],
              "Этажность": [10,9,2,10,5,5,9,6,5,10,9,2,10,5,5,9,6,5,5,3,2,5,5,5,5,10,6,5,5,14,16,6,10],
              "Цена на аренду": [12200,10450.90909,9250,9800,14800,9700,14700,29900,11800,12200,10450.90909
                                 ,9250,9800,14800,9700,14700,29900,11800,8450,10300,16200,10600,9550,8600
                                 ,10300,9150,22200,10100,21200,9097.222222,9100,13853.33333,21200]
             })
data.to_excel("datas.xlsx", index=False)
```

Comment: Можете привести в вопросе [воспроизводимый пример данных](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060)?

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, я добавил код

Comment: Также добавил данные, которые нужно указать в file_name

Comment: можете выложить файл с данными на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Comment: хорошо, сейчас отправлю

Comment: Спасибо за терпение! данные добавил с помощью pandas.DataFrame

Comment: для этих данных Start = от 1 до 14, step = 1 до 5, limit_train явно указать None, file_name = "datas", result_file_name = "Любое имя". В экселе вызываю только median_trainCount_scatterN()